# Wijmo grid grouping

Tags: wijmo, wijgrid

I have a wijmo grid where I added users to allow column drag and group by columns. But after dragging the column to group area the area hides or the grid overlaps the area . 
I have set allowcolmoving : true and showgrouparea: true .

Answer (score 0):

We are sorry to mention but we could not replicate the issue at our end using the latest version of Wijmo3 i.e. 3.20152.78

Please refer to the following link to download the latest version of Wijmo3:
http://wijmo.com/products/wijmo-3/

Kindly check your sample application with the latest version. If issue still persists, then we request you to please share a small stripped down sample application or modify the attached sample application replicating the issue so that we can look into the issue accordingly.

Please refer to the following link to download the sample application:
http://supportftp.componentone.com/WijGrid_GroupArea.zip